# How to match an element's background colour with 2 semi-transparent element background colours

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, css, c

I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/vr9Lykoj/)

In the fiddle there are 3 divs.

1. The one on the left is **purple**.
2. The one on the right is **blue**.
3. The one above the blue div has a yet **unknown** colour

The desired colour of the **third** div (the one laying over the blue div to the right) is that of the div on the left (the purple one).

The issue is that all the divs have an **opacity of 0.7**, and must remain (in order to see the content behind them).

My question, then, is how do I calculate the difference between the purple colour on the left and the blue colour on the right so that I may give give the third div a colour so that it matches the colour of the purple div on the left when it overlays the blue div on the right.

I am not asking for you to guess by eye, as I have many other colours to do this for, I would simply like to know if there is a calculation that allows me to do this using JQuery or Javascript?

I do not have any JS code to date as I have no idea where to even start.

**HTML**

```
<div id="target" class="opacity purple"></div>
<div id="actualBackground" class="opacity blue"></div>
<div id="sameColourAsTarget" class="opacity purple2"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    position:absolute;
}
#target{
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
}
#actualBackground{
    left:150px;
    top:0px;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
}
#sameColourAsTarget{
    left:150px;
    top:50px;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
.opacity{
    opacity:0.7;
}
.purple{
    background-color:rgb(152, 3, 214);
}
.blue{
    background-color:rgb(10, 127, 188);
}
.purple2{
    background-color:rgb(175, 3, 150);
}
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: See http://hslpicker.com/

Comment: Add more tags to question. This question is not specific to JavaScript, jQuery, or CSS. You need the general algorithm for this which could already exist in a number of other languages. Perhaps "Color", "Color processing"?

Comment: @Zaqx I realize this isn't specific to jQuery or JavaScript, if there are any other languages where this code exists, or where someone is able to create it, I'm willing to accept it as an answer, it would help me as well. I assumed jQuery and JavaScript would be easier for most people. I'm actually using this in C#, however displaying it on jsfiddle proves to be simpler than including other languages

Comment: I've added C and C# as tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vr9Lykoj/6/) for a pure Javascript solution.

```
/**
 * Gets the mixed color obtained by overlaying a front color
 * with the specified opacity over a solid back color.
 */
function mix(back, front, opacity) {
    var mixed = {
        r: (1 - opacity) * back.r + opacity * front.r,
        g: (1 - opacity) * back.g + opacity * front.g,
        b: (1 - opacity) * back.b + opacity * front.b
    }

    return mixed;
}

/**
 * Gets the front color that can be overlaid with the specified
 * opacity over a solid back color to get the same color as the
 * mixed color.
 */
function unmix(mixed, back, opacity) {
    var front = {
        r: (mixed.r - back.r) / opacity + back.r,
        g: (mixed.g - back.g) / opacity + back.g,
        b: (mixed.b - back.b) / opacity + back.b
    }

    return front;
}

/**
 * Converts an rgb string to a color object in the following form
 * {r: 255, g: 255, b: 255}
 */
function rgbToColor(rgb) {
    var matches = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);

    return {
        r: parseInt(matches[1]),
        g: parseInt(matches[2]),
        b: parseInt(matches[3])
    }
}

/**
 * Converts a color object of from {r: 255, g: 255, b: 255} to
 * an rgb string
 */
function colorToRgb(color) {
    var r = Math.round(color.r);
    var g = Math.round(color.g);
    var b = Math.round(color.b);

    return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}

// get properties of the back element
var backEl = document.getElementById("actualBackground");
var backStyle = window.getComputedStyle(backEl);
var backColor = backStyle.backgroundColor;
var backOpacity = backStyle.opacity;

// get properties of the target element
var mixedEl = document.getElementById("target");
var mixedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(mixedEl);
var mixedColor = mixedStyle.backgroundColor;
var mixedOpacity = mixedStyle.opacity;

// calculate the actual back color by mixing the back element's
// properties with solid white
var back = mix({
    r: 255,
    g: 255,
    b: 255
}, rgbToColor(backColor), backOpacity);

// calculate the actual target color by mixing the target element's
// properties with solid white
var mixed = mix({
    r: 255,
    g: 255,
    b: 255
}, rgbToColor(mixedColor), mixedOpacity);

// calculate the overlay's color by unmixing the back and the target
// colors with an opacity of 0.7 (could also be retrieved from the overlay element
var front = unmix(mixed, back, 0.7);

// get the overlay's element and apply the calculated color
var frontEl = document.getElementById("sameColourAsTarget");
frontEl.style.backgroundColor = colorToRgb(front);
frontEl.style.opacity = 0.7;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The code needs not explaining I have figured out how you have done it. If you'd like to, you can add explanations for possible future viewers of the question, although it isn't necessary. The division by zero is not an issue for me as these elements will remain at 0.7 opacity, so no fixing needed there for me. Thanks a ton

Comment: Great. I've added some comments anyway. To future readers: if you plan on applying this solution, note that the code probably needs some more validation, and that there's a division-by-zero risk in the calculations for `opacity: 0`.

Comment: I've changed the implementation a little to get rid of the double rounding. Also note that if there's a big difference between the target color and the back color, it becomes impossible to find a color that you can overlay with opacity 0.7 to get the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

According to your Fiddle, I believe you get the colour by doing this:

```
var temp = $("#target").css('background-color');
temp = temp.substring(4,14);
temp = temp.split(",");

var temp2 = $("#actualBackground").css('background-color');
temp2 = temp2.substring(4,14);
temp2 = temp2.split(",");

var result = [0,0,0]
for(var i=0; i < result.length; i++){
    result[i] = (parseInt(temp[i]) + parseInt(temp2[i])) / 2
}
result = "rgb("+result[0]+", "+result[1]+", "+result[2]+")";
$("#sameColourAsTarget").css("background-color", result);
```

Comment: You're not taking the opacity into account. When trying out your code in the fiddle, it doesn't come even close to the requested color. The question explicitly states that all the opacity settings must remain as is.